# detect when a session is no longer active

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, session

For my current project (using PHP - Codeigniter ) user can upload there photos to the server. If the user is not registered / logged in I am creating a temporary id for the user and creates a folder with same name. And after logging in/ register I can change the folder name to the user ID.

So if the user is not authenticating identity I need to delete that entire folder from my server.

And the problem I am facing is that I need to know when ever the session is no longer active. So I could delete the folders.

The pobablities I found are when closing the browser, if the user system gone switch off, etc I need to delete those folders.

It will be great help if some one could suggest me how to implement this functionality.

Some js functions could detect through any browser actions. I think it willl be better to have a comination of js and server side codes,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please refer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246378/detecting-user-inactivity-over-a-browser-purely-through-javascript

Comment: but its for user inactivity for an idle time. And it works only when the browser is open. (So the counter could find track the time out )

Comment: What does `delete folder from browser` mean? Assume that means server... use a temp directory until user logs in...and cron job to do cleanup

Comment: @charlietfl yeah I meant to delete form the server sorry for the confusion

Comment: Yes, best practice here would probably be to put all the unregistered user's files in a `tmp` folder, then run a `cron` job to clean that up daily, or something of that nature. You could also, do a simple database register of active sessions, and run a heartbeat on the client's browser that updates last activity time. Then reference that in your cron job to skip over any active sessions.

Comment: @LionelRitchietheManatee thank you for introducing me cron job. I was not aware of that, My plan was to run the script  on a regular intervel (like once in 3 days)