# Trouble moving code to Polymer component

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to implement some idle detection code. I have it working, thanks to [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246378/detecting-user-inactivity-over-a-browser-purely-through-javascript) SO posts, but I want it to be part of a Polymer Element so I can just stick `<idle-fire></idle-fire>` anywhere in my app and pass some parameters.  Here is what I have:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="idle-fire">

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'idle-fire',
        properties: {
            idlelimit: {
                type: Number,
                value: 10
            }
        },
        ready: function() {


        }
    });
</script>
</dom-module>

<script>
    var idleTime = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
        var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000); // 1 minute

        //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
        $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
            idleTime = 0;
        });
        $(this).keypress(function (e) {
            idleTime = 0;
        });
    });
    function timerIncrement() {
        idleTime = idleTime + 1;
        console.log("tick (" + idleTime + ")");
        if (idleTime >= 2) { // in minutes
            console.log("Idle event fired!")
        }
    }
</script>
```

If I try to move any piece of the `<script>` tag to the Polymer `ready` function it fails to work.  And with it the way it is, I can't access the `idlelimit` property.

Any direction appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried keeping your code outside of Polymer's constructor as it is

Comment: I should have mentioned, yes, it works, but then I don't have access to the parameters like `idlelimit`.  I will update the question.

Comment: you can access it using `document.querySelector('idle-fire').idlelimit`. By the way your have used **capital** `V`  for `value`. This will not work `v` should be lowercased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I try to move any piece of the `<script>` tag to the Polymer `ready` function it fails to work. And with it the way it is, I can't access the `idlelimit` property.

It's possible that you're not binding the context (i.e., `this`) properly when setting up your callbacks. If you forget to do it at all, the context for the timer callback would be the outer context (the `Window` object) instead of your Polymer object, where `idlelimit` is available.

Here's one way to set the context for the `timerIncrement` callback:

```
// in Polymer object
setupTimer: function() {
  setInterval(timerIncrement.bind(this), 1000);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use ES6 arrow functions to automatically bind the context for you:

```
// in Polymer object
setupTimer: function() {
  setInterval(() => {
    this.idleTime++; // `this` is Polymer object
  }, 1000);
}
```

Here's the conversion of that code to Polymer:

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'idle-fire',
    properties: {
      idlelimit: {
        type: Number,
        value: 10
      }
    },
    
    attached: function() {
      // Increment the idle time counter every second.
      this._idleInterval = setInterval(this._timerIncrement.bind(this), 1000);
      this._idleTime = 0;

      // Zero the idle timer on mouse movement or keypress.
      document.onmousemove = () => { this._idleTime = 0 };
      document.onkeypress =  () => { this._idleTime = 0 };
    },

    detached: function() {
      clearInterval(this._idleInterval);
    },

    _timerIncrement: function() {
      const idleTime = ++this._idleTime;
      console.log("tick (" + idleTime + ")", this.idlelimit);
      if (idleTime >= this.idlelimit) { // in seconds for this demo
        console.log("Idle event fired!");
        clearInterval(this._idleInterval);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <div>See timer in DevTools console</div>
  <div>Move your mouse over this document, or press any key to restart the timer</div>
  <idle-fire></idle-fire>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/bBmLZj?editors=1011)

FYI: You might consider using the already available [`<f-idlejs>`](https://github.com/firmfirm/f-idlejs/) element.

Comment: Thanks for the `idlejs` link!

Comment: @Scott No problem :)