# How to write global event(touch/click) handler in angular application?

Tags: angularjs, angular-timer, angular-touch

If angular application is not touched(mobile browser) or clicked for particular seconds, it should through a alert.
Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Take a look at this SO question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564602/how-to-know-browser-idle-time

Answer (score 1):

Best way, if You use Angular js, is to use Ng-Idle.

Source with demoes and git repo: http://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng-idle/