# Google chrome - extension chrome idle not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

Getting ERROR: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'queryState' of undefined`

how can i run the extension (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/idle ) from my code?

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name" : "Idle - Simple Example",
  "version" : "1.0.1",
  "description" : "Demonstrates the Idle API",
  "background" : {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions" : [ "idle" ],
  "browser_action" : {
    "default_icon" : "sample-19.png"
  },
  "icons" : {
    "16" : "sample-16.png",
    "48" : "sample-48.png",
    "128" : "sample-128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js:

```
var history_log = [];
chrome.idle.onStateChanged.addListener(function(newstate) {
  var time = new Date();
  if (history_log.length >= 20) {
    history_log.pop();
  }
  history_log.unshift({'state':newstate, 'time':time});
});
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  window.open('history.html', 'testwindow', 'width=700,height=600');
});
```

FAIL: in my code to get the chrome.idle.queryState, `http://localhost/index.html`:

```
<html>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  chrome.idle.queryState(5, function(state) {
    var time = new Date();
    alert("extension: " + state);
  });

});
</script>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

it only works when i use as chrome-extension:// but does not work if i try to use it from http:// or https://. My goal is to make it work from http:// or https:// (or iFrame opening chrome-extension invisibly if possible?)

[image]

Comment: i want to know on which page you are executing the DomContentLoaded event. is that page part of extension.

Comment: I am executing the DomContentLoaded event in index.html which is regular page part of site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having an extension open a website does not magically grant the site rights to use Chrome Extension API.

1. Simplest is to have `index.html` as part of the extension's files. Then you can use the API, but take note of the [Chrome's CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution) (you can't use inline scripts).
2. If your goal is specifically to provide a web page access to the Chrome API, the webpage will need to talk to the extension.

   There are [many methods for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26090563/sending-message-to-background-script/26095346#26095346), for example [`"externally_connectable"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage), or talking via a context script and shared DOM.

In any case: `chrome.idle` can only be called from extension's own pages, including but not limited to the background page.

Also, please use `chrome.windows.create` or `chrome.tabs.create` instead of `window.open` in an extension. It doesn't require special permissions.

Comment: I need to launch it as `https://example.com/phpetcetc` in that page i need to track the status. for that to make work what can i do please?

Comment: Its a KIOSK application, i must have to run it as http:// or https:// and from there i need to get the activity or idle state. is it impossible? or there is anyother way using iframe to the local extension url as chrome-extension:// ?

Comment: Wait, a kiosk application? Why are you trying to make it an extension then, and not an app?

Comment: Because in kiosk application i am using webRTC

Comment: So i must need WebRTC + idle state on the full-screen kiosk touch screen.

Comment: That's not an answer. WebRTC is fine in chrome apps. And if the only thing you need is idle state, why not use [pure web approaches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564602/how-to-know-browser-idle-time)? What's the benefit of `chrome.idle` / what's your scenario for it?

Comment: 1) Google chrome opens a site in my kiosk/full-screen as https://apprtc.appspot.com/custom which does the WebRTC part 2) beside that there is a touch button browse website, when they click on it, it has to open external sites such as `https://facebook.com https://youtube.com`, now when iframe is opening other origin url, then we do not get activity/idle states. Therefore the chrome.idle was perfect in my case.

Comment: Then you should do idle detection in the background, and then message that to your web app. There are many ways, I linked to some.