# Count Idle time on browser

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile

Already implemented something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564602/how-to-know-browser-idle-time) 
But it fails on mobile devices. As soon as the device browser goes in background (Screen lock/ user start another app / press home key) javascript counter stops counting idle time. I know this is OS behavior to optimize memory and CPU utilization but just curious is there any way to achieve expected behavior on mobile browser.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of counting, you should store a timestamp in memory, when it become active again, compare this timestamp with now, and then do your action.
You can do this with Date object and getTime().

Comment: yes that would help in some cases but it creates dependency to system time and if user changes system time intentionally or unintentionally this functionality will fail. I also thought of using server time for calculating time but making ajax call will extend session time even if user doesn't want to.

Comment: Agree with you, but most of devices are sync. It's rare a user has to change his time. In addition, he can also hack your script with a developper console, so if you want something secure and accurate, you have to manage this on server side.