# keep a tally of no movement in milliseconds on a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to track IDLE time (no mouse or keyboard movement) of a user on my page.  I want a running tally because when the user submits via ajax the call will subtract that time from the time spent on the page.

```
time on page =  (Date.now() - startTime) - idleTime.
```

should be easy I would think to stick something in function() for the custom javascript but not getting how to just tally.

Comment: How would you define idle time? Is it the time it takes to complete a server side function, is it because the user is not moving his mouse or not interacting with the website?

Comment: This post has the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564602/how-to-know-browser-idle-time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting idle time in JavaScript elegantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly)

Comment: I've looked at these other examples but none of them seem to keep track of the time that the user is not doing anything  AS A TALLY..

Comment: idle time meaning no mouse/keyboard movement but keep it as a running tally ... when the user clicks to submit their email I want it to subtract that idle time ..  All I need is the time after the page loads when the perform some particular action ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do it like that. You can get the total time it took from the `getIdleTime` method, and if you want to track some more events, you could do that through the `actionsToTrack` const

```js
function TimeKeeper(selector) {
  const timeKeeper = document.querySelector(selector);
  const actionsToTrack = ['mousemove', 'mouseenter', 'mouseleave', 'keyup', 'keydown', 'keypress'];

  let lastMoveTime = new Date();
  let idleTime = 0;
  
  // this updates the time and updates the element showing the inactive time
  let update = (newTime) => {
    idleTime += newTime;
    timeKeeper.innerHTML = `${idleTime} ms`;
  };

  // will execute for every different kind of action
  // you could potentially log the action to see if it got caught or not
  const trackAction = (action) => function() {
    lastMoveTime = new Date();
  };

  setInterval(() => {
    let moveTime = new Date();
    let diff = moveTime - lastMoveTime;
    // i don't see 100 ms of inactivity necessarily as idle, but okay
    if (diff >= 100) {
      update(diff);
      lastMoveTime = moveTime;
    }
  }, 100);

  // attaches the handlers
  Object.keys( actionsToTrack ).forEach(action => 
    document.body.addEventListener(actionsToTrack[action], trackAction( actionsToTrack[action] ) )
  );

  // returns the idle time
  this.getIdleTime = () => {
    return idleTime;
  };

  // resets the idle time
  this.reset = () => {
    idleTime = 0;
  };
}

var tk = new TimeKeeper('#idleTime');
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.timekeeper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="idleTime" class="timekeeper"></div>
```

Note that for a mousemove, the cursor has to pass the body itself, since I don't have any content i just stretched it...

Comment: awesome, this is the only place where this exists on Stack